# rewrite move up directory

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a rewrite rule where if you type:

> www.whatever.com/profile-one.php

that is the url you see, but the actual template page is:

> www.whatever.com/profile.php

Here are the lines in htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)([^/])$ http://www.whatever.com/$1$2/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule profile-(.*)\.php$ profile.php?name=$1
```

My problem is, if you visit a url like:

> www.whatever.com/second/profile-one.php

It still tries to bring back the profile page, even though the profile.php template does not exist in the "second" directory.  What would be the best way to prevent this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening due to wrong regex here. You need to use start anchor in your 2nd rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)([^/])$ http://www.whatever.com/$1$2/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^profile-(.*)\.php$ profile.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you once again, anubhava!